# Google webmasters report links to my site, which don't exist

Tags: google-search-console

Today, I logged in to my Google's webmaster tools, and I saw that it reported an unusual inbound links to my site. I saw some of them and navigated to them and tried to find the link to my site, but I couldn't find anything. Is there anything wrong with Google here? Have you experienced the same thing? What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is quite common. First, view the page source and search for your domain to make absolutely sure there is no link - it could be an image or some text that doesn't look like a link.

Next, check if the source page is part of some paginated content. If GWT says the link is from `example.com` it could now be pushed onto something like `example.com/archive?page=2`.

If you still don't find it then the link was likely just removed. Links come and go all the time.

Comment: thanks for replying. Imagine that you don't know a.com and you have never even surfed that website before. Then you go to GWT and you see that it reports not one, but something around 140 links from that site to your domain.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati another possibility I thought of is that it could be a spam site, built with the intention of getting "traffic by curiosity", in a similar way to [referer spam](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/11637/strange-incoming-links-appearing-on-site-statistics). Many webmasters see that they link to you and visit their site, and they manage to sell a product to a small percentage of webmasters.