# Weird referral traffic

Tags: traffic, web-applications, referrer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Strange incoming links appearing on site statistics](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/11637/strange-incoming-links-appearing-on-site-statistics)

I'm getting weird traffic from Japan, from a site called ime.nu
Why weird? because I'm not able to identify the link and also when going to their homepage link it just shows an Apache Test Page, while I'm seeing it is a pretty big site in analysis sites (Alexa Ranked 121 in JP)

Can someone help me understand the mystery?

Comment: They don't seem to have a default document page (index.html) setup. The only thing I could find was these odd 404 pages: http://ime.nu/whatever and here's a pagetest: http://www.webpagetest.org/result/120925_GK_YR1/

Answer (score 0):

If you are analysing your traffic from your HTTP referer log then this is probably [referer spam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referer_spam). The referer can be easily faked. Try matching up the IP addresses of the request and the domain you think it came from. I would guess that the traffic might even have originated from a completely different server, but one that is attempting to promote the site that is appearing in your logs.

Comment: I'm analyzing my traffic through Google analytics. Is that something they filter out? Also, is there probably a legit link in another place that is just transferring that to the server I'm seeing or is the whole thing probably fake?

Comment: Unfortunately the whole thing could be fake.

Comment: @w3d there's no such thing as HTTP referrer logs. There are access and error logs on web servers. Common in apache2 and NGINX, within the logs you can parse out referring URLs which linked to your site.

Comment: @Anagio: By _referer log_ I'm referring to whatever data the site owner is using to track their HTTP referers, whether this is from their own DIY logging, parsed from their access logs, google analytics, etc...